# How to use Stanford Named Entity Recognizer with multi-threads?

Tags: performance, stanford-nlp

Is it possible to use multi-threads with Stanford Named Entity Recognizer to increase the run time performance? If so, how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried / where have you searched for an answer to that question? Have you already written code? Please share your initial research.

Comment: Alright.  What prevents you from just throwing a bunch of threads at it?  Is the API not reentrant, or not designed to be used with multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

About a few months back i was struggling with the same problem. 
I wanted to do NE extraction on a large corpus while indexing it using a Lucene custom analyzer. 
The way i solved it, and this may or maynot be what you are looking for, is by using a producer/consumer construct.
I had N-4 threads reading documents and sending it to one of three named pipes on the system in a round robin fashion.
The receiving end of the three pipes were instances of stanfordNER in a Rest deployment form all having loaded the same models.

The code was python + multiprocessing. I would post the code but it has too many project specific things which i would need to clean.

Here are some resource pointers.
NER deploy
https://github.com/dat/stanford-ner/blob/master/ner-deploy.sh
Multiprocessing
http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

PS: N is the total number of threads your system can run.
Keep in mind that in my case i didn't have any constraint on Memory of the system as i had ample free memory (roughly 70GB)  So loading three instances of the NER on the same system didn't have much effect in terms of performance degradation.

Comment: This is the python wrapper around the http endpoint calls.  https://github.com/dat/pyner